# How do you close all ssh-add keys?

Tags: bash, ssh

Everytime I ssh into a server, I need to add the same ssh-key over and over again. So I have a script that does it for me, which worked fine for awhile. However now the server is complaining:

```
- You have too many files are open.  Close some files or increase your per-process descriptor limit.
while executing
"spawn bash -c "ssh-add [...some key]""
```

The full script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f                                                            

set key [lindex $argv 0]                                                        
set pass [lindex $argv 1]   

spawn bash -c "ssh-add /path/to/.ssh/$key"                               
expect "passphrase"                                                             
send "$pass\n"                                                                  
interact
```

I don't know enough about `spawn` and `ssh-add` to know what to do. When I run `ps -e`, there's only the bash process. Maybe this is because it's a shared host server? I guess I'm not using `spawn` correctly. How should I solve this and avoid the problem in the future?

Comment: Please show us the script you run that causes this.

Comment: @JuliePelletier, I've added the full script.

Comment: Wow. That is pretty awkward technique ...

Answer (score 0):

First of all check your open files limit:

```
$ ulimit -n
65536
```

If the value is too small, just increasing the limit should solve the issue. In case the limit is something like `65536`, then your script is probably doing something suspicious.

Then check which files are currently open:

```
lsof -u your_username
```

you can count then to see how many files needs to be opened by your script to reach the limit:

```
lsof -u your_username | wc -l
```

Btw. instead of manually adding ssh keys wouldn't it be easier to use `ForwardAgent`?

Comment: The limit is 1024. I didn't know about `ForwardAgent`, I just looked it up and this is definitely a better workflow than what I am doing. Back to this problem, how can I bust 1024 when `ps -e` only shows `bash`? Processes are hidden on a shared server? So how do I kill them?

Comment: @vega `ForwardAgent` has also some security issues, be sure to check that as well before using. `ps -e` will show processes, not files. Each process can be working with many files.